# Navbar not initializing in kendo ui mobile webpage

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

for some reason this navbar is not rendering correctly on the browser :

```
<header data-role="header">
    <div id="navbar-personalize" data-role="navbar" class="my-navbar">
        <div data-align="left">
            <img src="../../Images/dashboard6.png" alt="Dashboard"/>
        </div>

        <span data-role="view-title">Cart Summary</span>

        <div data-align="right">
            <a href="#merchandise-otherorders-view">
                <img src="../../Images/whoelse6.png" alt="Who else is going?"/>
            </a>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
```

I have other navbars just like this one all around my index file, and they all work fine, except for this one. It seems that KendoUI isn't initializing it all. By inspecting the code I can see that it's missing all of kendo's styling (like "km-navbar" and such).

It may have to do with the fact that I'm defining this header in each one of the views inside the file, instead of defining it in the app layout, but for some reason defining it inside the app layout doesn't work for me, it simply doesn't render at all.

I'm out of ideas, can somebody help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem today. Make sure that kendo.mobile.min.js is included on your page. The docs don't say to put it in, but adding that made it work for me.